# Add unique constrains as date from datetime column in mysql

Tags: mysql, unique

I need to create a unique constrains for my table which has date time but i need to make mid and date from createdttm as unique .
Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sampletable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdttm` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31826 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Answer (score 1):

This could easily be solved by adding a unique key for `mid` and the date part of `createdttm`:

```
ALTER TABLE `sampletable` ADD UNIQUE `un_idx`(`mid`, DATE(`createdttm`));
```

but, MySql does not allow the use of functions in the definition of an index.

What you can do is define a [virtual generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html) to be the date part of `createdttm` and then create the unique index based on that column and `mid`:

```
ALTER TABLE `sampletable` ADD COLUMN `created` DATE AS (DATE(`createdttm`));
ALTER TABLE `sampletable` ADD UNIQUE `un_idx`(`mid`, `created`);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=26a9a4a19ddbd6ecacf83802e3a760d4).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a combined unique index.

```
UNIQUE KEY `date key` (`mid`,`createdttm`),
```